# Global.asax OnApplicationStarted doesn't starting after refreshing application pool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax, application-pool

I start ASP.NET MVC application on my machine using iis.
Then i open iis go to application pools tab, select my application's pool and click "recycle".
After that global.asax code doesn't starting until i open any page of my application.

I think Global.asax should restart with app pool but why it doesn't happen?

Comment: This believe this is as intended. The application only starts once it gets a request. It will also shut down itself based on the inactivity timeout setting for your app pool and only start once a request is made (so ApplicationStarted will be hit again).

Answer (score 0):

Juha pretty much gave the answer, and I can confirm the answer is correct.

The `Application_Start` event runs only when the first request comes into ASP.NET. If you want it to run before the first *user* makes a request to the site you can use the [IIS Application Warmup](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) module that can be configured to make some requests to the site immediately after it is started. This is often used in large applications that can take a while to warm up.